# How can I make Bridge table from 2 Model classes using hibernate annotation configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, nhibernate-mapping

How to make **Bridge table** using annotation using **Hibernate/JPA** configuration.

> 1: BookModel
>   2: UserModel

now I have to create a bridge table by these two by fields

> **book_id** and **user_id**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to implement `Many to Many` relationship between your entities. So for this, If you have list of `Books` in User model, then you can annotate the list as following:

```
public class UserModel {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "book_user_table", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
    private List<BookModel> books;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

and in BookModel, if you have list of users, then you need to use `@mappedBy()` annotation like following:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books") 
private List<UserModel> users;
```

This will generate the 3rd table, which will have the name `book_user_table`, with your required columns. See this for detailed explanation:  https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from your quesrtion is, you want to know how to map book and user so that there is many to many association between these entities.

If so,  you need to specify  `@ManyToMany` on both the associations and make one of them as inverse and the other end with `@JoinTable`. An [example mapping](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many) here. Snippet below.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Employee_Project", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id") }
    )
Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

On the inverse end,

```
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
    private Set<Employee> employees;
```